# PhpStorm can't resolve package import even though it exists (react-router-dom)

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, node-modules, react-router-dom, jetbrains-ide

I am using React (16.12.0) with PhpStorm (2019.3.1).

The package I am importing is react-router-dom (5.1.2)

I will write the following import:

```
import { NavLink, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

Both packages are imported properly by webpack/babel and the page renders properly when I use both Switch and NavLink.

However purely from the IDE-perspective, I get a warning about Switch: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Switch'`

It is weird because it is obviously there, and I checked in `/node_modules/react-router-dom` and `Switch.js` is there.

Strangely on previous versions of PhpStorm (before several updates and plugin imports and other changes), the Switch import was accurately found by PhpStorm.

I have not updated react-router-dom recently and am using its latest stable build.

Any ideas as to why it might be missing Switch?

**EDIT:**
I have realized it may be because PhpStorm is having difficulty importing a commonJS module.

I tried changing the Javascript compilation method from React JSX to ECMA 6. That didn't work.

I also tried importing some build libraries for react-router-dom, and that worked for recognizing the `Route` import strangely but not `Switch`.

I also tried invalidating the PhpStorm cache and restarting the app, but that didn't work either.

**EDIT 2:**
Per an answer, I have tried to use option+enter (alt+enter on windows) while my cursor is within `react-router-dom` to try to install a typescript package, but I don't get the same suggested action as shown on the JetBrains website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

All it suggests is switching single quotes to double quotes.

[image]

Also I have already installed @types/react-router-dom. Perhaps there is another one that I am missing?

[image]

**EDIT 3:**
The correct answer was to install `@types/react-router`. For some reason `@types/react-router-dom` is deceivingly NOT what solves this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js` exports `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, `Link` and `NavLink`, but doesn't export `Switch`, it's not explicitly defined there.
For better completion/type hinting, you can install Typescript stubs for the package: put cursor on `"react-router-dom"` in import statement, hit `Alt+Enter`, choose **Install TypeScript definitions for better type information:**:

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

Comment: Figured it out! I installed @types/react-router and that did the trick!

Comment: The above answer is not complete. You have to install both @types. react-router and react-router-dom in order to have complete type resolving. For the components like Route from react-route

Comment: I don't know what the Mac equivalent is to Alt+Enter so I downloaded the packages in the preferences window and it fixed the issue.