# Switch and Router modules missing from react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Title of my question says it all. I've been trying to create a React app with several "pages" using react-router-dom. Basically what I've done is prompt "npx create-react-app", create a few JS page files just to test the thing and prompt a"npm install react-router-dom". Nothing else.

Now when I try to import the Switch module from react-router-dom, my IDE (I'm using Jetbrains Webstorm) doesn't find the dependency. I've checked manually by for the missing dependencies inside the module folder at node_modules, and the dependency is really not there.

I've read several tutorials on react-router-dom, and nobody says anything about Switch being deprecated or something like that, so that can't be the case.

I don't know if any other information would be of help, but feel free to point it out in case there's more info I can provide. Any help would be appreciated.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "react-router-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your package.json?, to see which version of react and react router are you using?, also a code snippet of your Switch import

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot of the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Sure, I've added the package.json file in the original question. As for the import, a simple  "  import Switch from 'react-router-dom'  " won't be possible since I can't find "Switch" on react-router-dom.

Comment: Did you get an answer on this im getting the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Updated your v5 of react-router-dom to v6 and replace:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path={`${match.path}/me`}>
      <OwnUserProfile />
    </Route>
     <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`}>
        <UserProfile />
      </Route>
 </Switch>
```

in V6 same example

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
 </Routes>
```

See the upgrading doc in [react-routers](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

Answer (score 3):

This is a WebStorm IDE issue, not a problem with react-router-dom; the Switch component works just fine, it's WebStorm that is not able to find the dependency.

You mention that

> I've checked manually by for the missing dependencies inside the module folder at node_modules, and the dependency is really not there.

but if you check in node_modules/react-router-dom the Switch.js file is indeed there.

You might try the steps outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015377/phpstorm-cant-resolve-package-import-even-though-it-exists-react-router-dom) answer (it's for PhpStorm, but applies to WebStorm as well).

For me it did not work so I will have to live with the IDE warning.

Plese note that but problem goes away if Switch is imported from react-router instead of react-router-dom:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import {Switch} from 'react-router'
```

Since, according to this [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648) "react-router-dom re-exports all of react-router's exports" maybe is this re-export that confuses WebStorm.